# Compact subspaces of a union of open spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Given a finite open cover ${\mathcal A}=\{A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n\}$ of a Hausdorff space, what is the general form of the compact space?

Can it be of the following form: 
\begin{eqnarray}
K=K_1\cup K_2\cup\cdots K_n
\end{eqnarray}
where $K_i\subset A_i$ is compact.

Can the condition be relaxed, e.g. infinite open cover, or any other condition to be imposed so that we can get any other argument?

Comment: Yes, it's true (assuming your original space is compact, which seems implied but not stated explicitly).  Compact Hausdorff spaces are normal.  From here you may use the 'shrinking lemma' for normal spaces.

Comment: Regarding the infinite cover, you would want to assume your Hausdorff space is locally compact and -paracompact- in which case it is again normal, or regular Lindelof etc.  There are lots of conditions sufficiently strong, but it will no longer necessarily be true without additional assumptions beyond Hausdorffness.  There are spaces where you xan get closed, but not compact, refinements as you desire (e.g. the rationals).  So you need some local compactness criterion as well as a global separation property.

Comment: @JohnSamples Many thanks for the helpful comments!